# How To Change Codeigniter Pager Parameter position

Tags: pagination, continuous-integration, codeigniter-2

my url is mycontroller/function/apple/pagingpram

how can I change the parameter position of codeigniter uri pram

I want url like this:

mycontroller/function/pagingpram/apple/oranything

Answer (score 0):

Using this in the pagination configuration

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 4; // where 4 is the pager parameter postion
```